# TextBlock Style to always use Run Tag

Tags: c#, wpf, arabic, right-to-left

In WPF Arabic Mode (FlowDirection="RightToLeft").

When i give a number like **-24.7%** it will print this as **%24.7-**

Following code will fix the above mentioned issues.

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Run">
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
    </Style>      

</Window.Resources>

<Grid FlowDirection="RightToLeft" >
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="114,127,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" Height="97">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="-24.7%" ><Run></Run></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now i want to put the `<run><run>` tag to all of my Text Blocks Contents, How can i achieve this, So i don't have to replace all of my TextBlocks in the code.

How to do this by creating a Style...??

*note: I can't go to the TextAlign=Right solution as i can't edit all the textblockes in the application*

Comment: You probably want to create a usercontrol that is a textblock with the run tags inside of it, and then use that.

Comment: @VibeeshanRC do your TextBlocks only have negative numbers?  If not, and we reverse all runs (and TextBlocks) wont that reverse the Arabic?  that is a bad side effect, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say I like your approach, but I don't know Arabic gotchas and your situation, so won't argue about that. You can achieve what you want using attached properties (or blend behaviors). Like this:

```
public static class StrangeAttachedProperty {
    public static bool GetAddRunByDefault(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(AddRunByDefaultProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAddRunByDefault(DependencyObject obj, bool value) {
        obj.SetValue(AddRunByDefaultProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddRunByDefaultProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AddRunByDefault", typeof (bool), typeof (StrangeAttachedProperty), new PropertyMetadata(AddRunByDefaultChanged));

    private static void AddRunByDefaultChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var element = d as TextBlock;
        if (element != null) {
            // here is the main point - you can do whatever with your textblock here
            // for example you can check some conditions and not add runs in some cases
            element.Inlines.Add(new Run());
        }
    }
}
```

And in your resources set this property for all text blocks:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="local:StrangeAttachedProperty.AddRunByDefault" Value="True" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Run">
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```